# Find radius of convergence and calculate sum $ \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{3n + 2}}{3n + 2} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$ \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{3n + 2}}{3n + 2} $$
For radius: I have tried to represent in the form of :$$  \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} x ^n a_n $$ to use standart methods, but I failed.
For sum calculation: I tried to represent it as Taylor series, but I coudn't find untion that fit it.
I tried to take derivative, sum, then integrate result, but it also won't help.

Comment: What went wrong this the last line? That should work

Comment: Why can't you write it down as a power series?

Comment: If you integrate $\sum x^{3n+1}$ term by term you should get something useful.

Comment: I think I find fool mistake in my solution. I'm sorry for this post)

Comment: Funny, you ask for the radius of convergence and for the sum and you accept an answer leaving the sum untouched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The series diverges for $x=1$, so its radius of convergence $R$ is smaller than or equal to $1$. If $x$ is such that $|x| < 1$, the series converges absolutely by comparison with the geometric series $\sum_{n\geq 0}{|x|^n}$. Then $R=1$.

**EDIT: I missed the sum part**

The series defines a smooth function $f:(-1,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0}{\frac{x^{3n+2}}{3n+2}}$ for $x$ in $(-1,1)$. Now $$f'(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0}{x^{3n+1}} = x\sum_{n\geq 0}{x^{3n}} = x\sum_{n\geq 0}{(x^{3})^n} = x \cdot \frac{1}{1-x^3} = \frac{x}{1-x^3}$$

Writing that expression with partial fractions you get $$f(x) = \int{f'(x) \, dx} = \int{\frac{x}{1-x^3} \, dx} = \frac{1}{3}\int{\frac{1}{1-x} + \frac{x-1}{x^2 + x + 1} \, dx}$$

That last part is easy. If you have any trouble go through your notes on methods of integration and you will certainly find something useful.

Comment: @lolaspekt Take a look at the edit.

Answer (score 1):

As usual, take the $\;n\,-$ th roots test to the whole thing in absolute value:

$$\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{x^{3n+2}}{3n+2}\right|}=\frac{|x|^3\sqrt[n]{x^2}}{\sqrt[n]{3n+2}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}|x|^3$$

Thus, for $\;|x|^3<1\iff |x|<1\;$ we have convergence, and the interval of convergence is $\;[-1,1)\;$ .

Another way: write

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{3n+2}}{3n+2}=x^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{3n}}{3n+2}$$

And now just substitute in the sum $\;z:=x^3\;$ , so we get a power series around zero

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{3n+2}\implies\;\text{Cauchy-Hadamard formula gives}\;\;\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac1{3n+2}\right|}=\frac1{\sqrt[n]{3n+2}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1$$

and we get the convergence radius $\;R=1\;$, as before.

**For the series sum**: we can put

$$f(x):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{3n+2}}{3n+2}\stackrel{\text{for}\;|x|<1}\implies f'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{3n+1}=x\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(x^3\right)^n=\frac x{1-x^3}=-\frac x{(x-1)(x^2+x+1)}\implies$$

$$f(x)=-\int\frac{x\,dx}{(x-1)(x^2+x+1)}=-\frac13\left(\int\frac{dx}{x-1}-\int\frac{x-1}{x^2+x+1}dx\right)=$$

$$=-\frac13\left(\log|x-1|-\frac12\int\frac{2x+1}{x^2+x+1}dx+\frac32\int\frac{dx}{\left(x+\frac12\right)^2+\frac34}\right)=$$

$$=-\frac13\left(\log|x-1|-\frac12\log(x^2+x+1)+\sqrt3\arctan\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt3}\right)+C$$

Now just substitute $\;x=0\;$ to find out $\;C\;$ :

$$0=f(0)=-\frac13\left(0-0+\sqrt3\arctan\frac1{\sqrt3}\right)+C=-\frac1{\sqrt3}\frac\pi6+C\implies C=\frac{6\sqrt3}\pi$$

and from here, finally:

$$f(x)=-\frac13\log\frac{|x-1|}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}-\frac1{\sqrt3}\arctan\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt3}+\frac{6\sqrt3}\pi$$

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody addressed the second part of the question

$$
S(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{3n+2}}{3n+2} \\
D_xS = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{3n+1} = x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left ( x^{3} \right )^{n} = \frac{x}{1-x^3} \\
\text{Since} \ S(0) = 0, \ \text{we can find} \ S(x) \ \text{by solving} \\
S(x) = \int_{0}^{x}\frac{t}{1-t^3} \ \mathrm{d}t = \frac{1}{3}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{1-t} - \frac{1-t}{1+t+t^2} \ \mathrm{d}t
$$

That last integral is a little messy, but it's easy to solve.